# Pythonでの配列とif文についてです。

Tags: python, array

REST APIで提供されているサービスを用いて、Pythonの配列へデータを取得したいと考えています。

対象のAPIは、URLの最後の文字列を変更することによって取得できるデータが変わるため、一度に取得できるように、配列とif文を用いてみました。
しかし「AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only」というエラーメッセージが出てしまう状態です。

api_dataが読み込み専用だといわれているのは分かるのですが、これに対しどう対処すべきかが判断できず、以下のソースについて、ご助言をいただけますと幸いです。

```
import requests

# api info
url = 'https://hogehoge.com/'
endpoint = 'api/'
moji = [
        'abcdefg',
        'none',
        'hijklmn',
        'opqrstu',
        'vwxyz'       
    ]


# 配列「moji」のデータ数だけループしてデータ取得（0からカウント）
api_data = []
for count in range(0,len(moji)):

    if moji[count] == 'none':
        api_data.append= ('none')
    else:
        api_data.append = requests.get(url + endpoint + moji[count])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` はメソッドなので、代入するものでは無いです。
あと、`requests.get()` は結果の `text` を格納するのでは？
以下のようにしてみてください。

```
    if moji[count] == 'none':
        api_data.append('none')
    else:
        api_data.append(requests.get(url + endpoint + moji[count]).text)
```